# How to detect if a mouse button was pressed on a QWebView?

Tags: python, pyqt

[I'm developing a Web Browser](https://github.com/EricsonWillians/Open-Browser) with PyQt4 and here's the part of the code that creates QWebViews:

```
def compose_tab(self, index):
        self.tabs[index].append(QtWebKit.QWebView())
        self.tabs[index][0].setLayout(self.tabs[index][1])
        self.tabs[index][1].addWidget(self.tabs[index][2])
        self.tabs[index][2].connect(self.tabs[index][2], QtCore.SIGNAL("linkClicked(const QUrl&)"), self.update_link)
        self.tabs[index][2].load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
        self.url_field.setText("http://www.google.com")
```

I want to detect when a mouse button is pressed on a QWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) you can see that this class inherits from [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html). This means that it should have access to all the event handlers found on the `QWidget` class.

These include [`mousePressEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) which is the most generic, and [`contextMenuEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#contextMenuEvent) which specifically works for registering right-click events.

There is also a specific signal for handling custom context menus [`customContextMenuRequested`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) which might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

For future lost souls, here's how I did it:

```
class CQWebView(QtWebKit.QWebView): 

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event) == QtGui.QMouseEvent:
            if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("FIRST_BUTTON_PRESSED"))
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("MIDDLE_BUTTON_PRESSED"))
            elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("RIGHT_BUTTON_PRESSED"))
```

**Although I have to warn you**, the "linkClicked(const QUrl&)" signal ceases to be emitted after you do this, so you'd need to emit it on your own (I've tested it, it's possible).